# Best way to detect browser state changes

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, history.js

And with state I mean URL changes, preserving browser history.back() and being able to update the page (through a callback I guess) when there is any change.

I've tried several methods, and each one has its pros and cons.
For example, I like the way Backbone.js manages the URLs with its Router because it works via the window.location.hash (#) and if you change the URL manually it's catched by the Router allowing you to perform manual changes in an easy way.
The thing I don't like about Backbone is the URLs being in this format "#/a/b/c/d/e" (against the classic http standard "?a=1&b=2&c=3". That means that the URL parameters needs to be in certain order and they don't have name. Of course you can fix that parsing the URL and treating the Router expression as a single string, so it's not a big problem.
Also, I think using Backbone just for its Router it's a bit overkill (including the whole BackBone just for that), so I'd like other solutions.

The next one is History.js, which is supossed to provide compatibility for the new HTML5 standard?
But I don't like its behaviour as much as the Backbone's one. I mean, in an HTML5 browser, the # is converted to ? and if you change something in the URL the whole page is reloaded.
Also, due to its lack of Router, you need to set some more listeners, like $(window).bind('statechange') and $(window).bind('hashchange'). Again this is not a big problem, but I'd like to know if there are other ways to do this.

I always say that "there's no a right way to do something, but different ways to achieve it". But to be able to choose one of that ways, I'd like to know about different possibilities.

What do you think about this problem, which is more and more common when developing Single Pages?
I've researched a bit, but all the answers I found are quite old (> 1 year+) so I'm interested on the state of art...

Comment: Being scared of using the "whole" Backbone doesn't seem to make sense to me.  Backbone was built as a library and not a framework.  It's made to use only what you need for your site. Sure, it tries to provide a more complete solution, but as everyone knows Backbone doesn't give you all the pieces of a website.  With all that said, the whole thing is only 6.5k!  Using Backbone for just the router function isn't a bad idea.  In fact, that's how Instagram does it.  They only use Backbone for the Router function.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, after seeing its size it's not a bad idea. Actually it's my first choice, since I like its behaviour :)
It's just I'd like to know other choices ;)

(I even thought about having a file only with the needed part of Backbone for the Router function, but after seeing its size I think it's not worth it lol)

Comment: Yea, actually Backbone Router & and the Backbone.history class, is probably the only opinionated part of Backbone and I agree with that opinion =)